# How to hide one column in grid while exploring to excel

Tags: asp.net

I showed data in gridview.There are lot of column,so used scroll bar to grid.For finding out perticular record,used auto generated select button.Suppose I select one record,it become different in colour.When I exporting data to excel,it shows that coloured column and select button also in excel .So I want to hide that select button and color of row of selected column.Even when I am taking diffrent record,that time also showes one row colored.I want liked this when I am selecting one item from dropdownlist,gridview should get disappered and on button clicked gridview should appered.Gridview has paging and column are auto-generated.

Comment: Where from Excel came in in this? Are you exporting? Can you re-write the post and make it comprehensible?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using GridView's `RenderControl` to export the data. This method writes the current html of GridView. If you want exported data to be formatted other than the GridView's current format then, I suggest that you to use [HTML Table](http://knvn.blog.com/2011/08/02/export-data-to-excel-without-using-interop/) method to export the data.

Comment: Thanks for ur help Knvn.I solved that problem by using If(Gridview.Column.count > 0) { //make visible = false}